# Div doesn't appear after using v-if statement

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

```html
<div class="min-h-screen flex" ref="mapDiv"></div>
<div class="bg-white absolute top-0 w-full overflow-y-auto"></div>
```

This is how it looks
[image]

Whenever I add to this div `v-if`
`<div class="bg-white absolute top-0 w-full overflow-y-auto" v-if="settingsToggled"></div>`

The div doesn't show up at all, even after being triggered to true. Screenshot:

[image]

I am returning settingsToggled in the setup function.

This is the code that triggers it:

```js
export function AvatarControl(controlDiv, settingsToggled) {
    const controlUI = document.createElement("div");
    controlUI.style.width = "100px";
    controlUI.style.margin = "10px"
    controlUI.style.height = "100px";
    controlUI.style.borderRadius = "8px"
    controlUI.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://www.pngkey.com/png/full/114-1149878_setting-user-avatar-in-specific-size-without-breaking.png')"
    controlUI.style.backgroundPosition = "center"
    controlUI.innterHTML = "Avatar";
    controlUI.style.zIndex = "9999";
    controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);
    controlUI.addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log(settingsToggled)
        settingsToggled = !settingsToggled
    })
  }
```

Anyone knows what might be the issue here?
Can I not modify the `settingsToggled` from outside this component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `AvatarControl`, `settingsToggled` appears to be a Boolean (based on `settingsToggled = !settingsToggled`), while your screenshot shows it as a `ref`, so I'm guessing you are passing the `ref`'s value to `AvatarControl` like this:

```js
// MyComponent.vue
new AvatarControl(controlDiv, settingsToggled.value)
```

But Booleans are passed by value, so the function can't modify the original variable like that. However, the function *can* modify the value of a `ref` argument:

```js
// MyComponent.vue
new AvatarControl(controlDiv, settingsToggled)

// AvatarControl.js
export function AvatarControl(controlDiv, settingsToggled) {
    const controlUI = document.createElement("div");
    //...
    controlUI.addEventListener("click", () => {
        settingsToggled.value = !settingsToggled.value
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Should I use `new` before calling AvatarControl function?

Answer (score 0):

You need a component data property for `settingstoggled` otherwise vue `v-if` hook will not find it.

Try like this in your .vue file:

```
data () {
   return {
      settingstoggled: true
  }
}
```

You can find more info on component data [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function).

Comment: do you see this is vue 3 tag?